# Turn off IPV6_V6ONLY or two listening sockets

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

Is it better to have two listening sockets one ipv4 and one ipv6 or to have one ipv6 socket that has had ipv6 only turned off. I would like to support both ipv4 and ipv6 from the start so I don't want to have to redo it later and have it hacked together. From what I can tell there isn't any problems with having ipv6 only turned off but I don't have much experience in dealing with ipv6 networking. What may or may not go wrong with this problem.

Comment: Whatever you choose: make sure your application can run in IPv4-only, IPv6-only and dual stack environments. The first IPv6-only networks are already appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are operating system out there which just don't support providing both protocols over the same socket. There you can switch off `IPV6_V6ONLY` as much as you want, it will have no effect.

If you want to stay compatible with these systems - Windows XP is an example - you'll have to work with two sockets.